# UNION SELECT not displaying all columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, union

I have a couple of `VIEW`s which get nested into a larger `VIEW` used as a report.

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
    SELECT table1.col1 AS t1c1, table1.col2 AS t1c2
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.col1 = 0
;

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

SELECT * FROM view1;
+-------------------+
|  t1c1  |   t1c2   |
+--------+----------+
|    0   |  t1stuff |
+--------+----------+
|    0   | t1stuff2 |
+--------+----------+
```

.

```
CREATE VIEW view2 AS
    SELECT table2.col1 AS t2c1, table2.col2 AS t2c2
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.col1 = 5
;

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

SELECT * FROM view2;
+-------------------+
|  t2c1  |   t2c2   |
+--------+----------+
|    5   |  t2stuff |
+--------+----------+
|    5   | t2stuff2 |
+--------+----------+
```

.

I then bring them together into a "report" view as so:

```
CREATE VIEW view3 AS
    SELECT * FROM view1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM view2
;

SAMPLE OUTPUT:
SELECT * FROM view3;
+-------------------+
|  t1c1  |   t1c2   |
+--------+----------+
|    0   |  t1stuff |
+--------+----------+
|    0   | t1stuff2 |
+--------+----------+
|    5   |  t2stuff |
+--------+----------+
|    5   | t2stuff2 |
+--------+----------+
```

INSTEAD of the expected:

```
+-------------------+--------+----------+
|  t1c1  |   t1c2   |  t2c1  |   t2c2   |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|    0   |  t1stuff |        |          |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|    0   | t1stuff2 |        |          |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|        |          |   5    | t2stuff  |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|        |          |   5    | t2stuff2 |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

How can I achieve the expected results?

Comment: The `UNION` and `UNION ALL` set operators combine sets based on column position within each set. Every set combined must "match", in  terms of the number of columns in the set, and the datatypes of each column. (The names of the columns aren't important; the names of the columns in the resulting combined set are derived from the first set.) In your example, the `UNION` operator is performing the requested operation, per the specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One would question why you are doing this in a single query to begin with if none of the data is related and don't even share columns. But in any case you would have to specify all the columns:

```
select col1 as t1c1, col2 as t1c2, null as t2c1, null as t2c2
from view1
union all
select null as t1c1, null as t1c2, col1 as t2c1, col2 as t2c2
from view2
```

Comment: Doing it in a single query so that my accounting people can view a snapshot on the same spreadsheet of stuff occurring on our various sales channels (they are related, just not the data presented). I'm going to try your suggestion now.

Comment: +1. Using the `UNION ALL` set operator avoids the extra overhead of identifying and removing duplicate rows that would be performed if the `UNION` operator was used instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM view1
FULL OUTER JOIN view2
  on 1=0
```

Unions are used to join like data in this case you're not wanting data in the same columns
A join seems more appropriate here...

Full outer return all records from each set since we don't want any to match we can use 1=0 so that they don't relate but you get the expected result.

bah... mySQL doesn't support full outer joins... so a union is required. Burned by non-ancii standard engines again.

Comment: hmm.. this seems to complain: `near 'OUTER JOIN view2 ON 1=0'` -- entire query line: `CREATE VIEW view3 AS
    SELECT * FROM view1 FULL OUTER JOIN view2 ON 1=0;`

Comment: mySQL support for full outer join doexn't exist.